# Property 'x' is missing in type '() => x' but required in type 'x'

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

Error: `Property 'Control' is missing in type '() => Controls' but required in type 'Controls'.`

```
export class Controls {
   Control: Control[];
}

page.Sections.push({
    ....
    Controls: () => {
      const c = new Controls();
      c.Control = new Array<Ctrl>();
      section.VisualComponents.forEach(vc => {
          c.Control.push({
            ....
            ....

        });
      });
      return c;
    }
  });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are required to have `Controls[]` array but are assigning a function `Controls: () => {`:

```
export class Controls {
   Control: Control[]; /// HERE
}

page.Sections.push({
    ....
    Controls: () => { // HERE 
      const c = new Controls();
      c.Control = new Array<Ctrl>();
      section.VisualComponents.forEach(vc => {
          c.Control.push({
            ....
            ....

        });
      });
      return c;
    }
  });
```

## Fix

Call the function to get its return value, e.g :

```
const createControls = () => {
      const c = new Controls();
      c.Control = new Array<Ctrl>();
      section.VisualComponents.forEach(vc => {
          c.Control.push({
            ....
            ....

        });
      });
      return c;
    };
export class Controls {
   Control: Control[];
}

page.Sections.push({
    ....
    Controls: createControls()
  });
```